# affecting existing RadioButtonList to set a default value

Tags: c#, javascript, html, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have an existing `RadioButtonList` on a page and need to set the second button to be checked as default instead of the first.

I probably need to do it with `javascript` on the page as I cannot edit the original control.

```
<list:RadioButtonList runat="server" Class="class" Text="text"
AlternativeText="alternative text"   />
```

Any idea how i can detect the control and set its default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use ASP.NET you can set the following:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I've added the attribute Selected="True", so you always have a default value selected.

You can also do this in code:

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == -1) //-1 is the indication of none selected
{
    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 2; //select index 2 (can also be value or text)
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it, I just affected the existing controls by calling them :) THANKS!